# hibernate удаляет данные

Tags: hibernate, java-ee

Ситуация следующая, ранее я не работал с hibernate и мне достался проект с ним. Потихньку разбираюсь. Есть одна важная особенность проекта. В предидущий раз, когда его запускали на продакшн, он очистил таблицы, которые использовал, а там лежали важные данные.

Предыдущий программист уволился, уточнить что случилось не у кого. МОй опыт с  hibernate  нулевой, предположить почему так случилось не могу.

Подскажите, что могло привести к такому поведению программы? Любые варианты, я потом их буду проверять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего выбрана стратегия создания таблиц при старте приложения, это конфигурируется либо через xml, либо через properties файлы. Параметр может называться **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** или **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**. Нужно будет с **create** поменять на **update**